# Hidden communities sort order

Tags: support, profile-page, sorting, hidden-communities

In the user profile page visible communities sorted by earned reputation. For hidden communities sort order is differs. As far as I see they sorted by hiding time (oldest is first):

> [image: communities]

More over this sorting is differs on the *Edit Profile & Settings* page:

> [image: settings]

What is a purpose to use different sort orders here? Should it make same as made for visible communities (I mean only for list on the first picture)?

Comment: It appears that the visible and hidden communities under the **Settings / Hide communities** option are in alphabetical order now. I notice that yours is not in alphabetical order, so there seems to have been a change in this listing at some point. Is your listing in alphabetical order now too?

Comment: @PeterJames no, the order still looks [shuffled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXfQ8.png) for me.

Comment: OK, so the order is alphabetical URL order of the site. The URL for "Ask Different" is apple.stackexchange.com and this explains why it comes before Area51. That probably means that nothing has changed since you posted this.

Comment: @PeterJames Please note that this ordering is coincidental, not intentional, and could change at any time. I'm not going to go deep here but, in several places on the site, lack of apparent sorting (and defaulting to something you might observe as logical) has to do with how SQL Server handles a missing (or non-deterministic) `ORDER BY`, and how it handles that can change based on a variety of factors.