# Limit the visible number of hidden communities in the profile

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, hidden-communities

The number of items of visible communities in the profile isn’t exceed 5, but the number of items for hidden communities isn’t limited (actually is limited by SE sites count):

> [image: list of communities]

My suggestion is to limit the visible items of hidden communities in the profile in the same way as for unhidden communities. This will at least prevent the large empty area on the right column of the page, i.e. page vertical space will be used more evenly.

Comment: [Related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291708/339911)

Comment: Are you still seeing this? I think it now has a scroll bar and therefore is less obnoxious.

Comment: @Laurel you're right, but that [scroll bar has weird style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qduzN.png). It seems that there is a bug/fr post about it.