# Complete Listing of Communities on Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, user-accounts, stack-exchange-button, communities-list

Can a complete listing of Stack Exchange communities one belong to be included in ones user's profile in Stack Exchange or at least a link to them?

Currently, there is a Community section in my profile where I can see only five sites out of several I belong to; and an edit link where one can choose to hide some communities. A list of all communities a user belongs to will aid navigation to different communities a great deal.

Comment: If you make your communities invisible, more will be visible :)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312317/limit-the-visible-number-of-hidden-communities-in-the-profile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the activity tab of your profile, there is an accounts listing right at the bottom. That has an all accounts button that links to the page with all your accounts on stack exchange.com

[image]

Comment: Took a little effort to find it. But the Community section already under the profile tab would be where one using the feature for the first time would expect it to be.

Comment: @UdoE. I think you have a point since on someone else's profile, there's a link to "view all" from there, but it's replaced with "edit" on your own profile.

Comment: Oh! I had no idea there was such an accounts listing. Presumably I never scrolled all the way down on the new activity page; curiously, “Accounts” is not included in the left sidebar where links to all the other sections are, hence it is well hidden. This looks like a bug.

Comment: BTW, it’s not “right at the bottom”, but above the “Active bounties” and “Votes cast” sections.