# Why aren't all communities shown in the user profile?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, user-accounts, linked-accounts

When I go to my own profile, only five communities are shown under **Communities**.

Why aren't all displayed? For one there is an, about, 1340 pixels empty space below the grouping, and the hassle of going to the bottom of the page and navigate trough various pages to find the community I am registered at seems rather non-user-friendly (easier ways are shown in comments and answer).

At least have a “show all” or the like option.

**As an added note:** I have more focus on the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) then *alternative ways* as I think it is the more intuitive and user friendly approach.

By all means; keep the other ways, but why not have it where I guess a lot of people both remember to have seen a list and likely is a place they go to look for it? At least my thought is that *Profile* is a natural place to look for it.

[image]

^^^
It continues even further down. (And, yes, that picture is rather user-unfriendly as well; but as an afterthought it is proving the point.)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: In part; I.e. it is a way to show it that likely is easier then using the “look at all sites” approach, but still think it does not answer why one simply can not show it on Profile page. As in focusing on user friendliness.  At least I find the listing there to be the most intuitive place to look.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit the visible number of hidden communities in the profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312317/limit-the-visible-number-of-hidden-communities-in-the-profile) - opposite request for other list, which shows how it was implemented.

Answer (score 3):

> Why aren't all communities shown in profile?

Probably because there's an easier way to get to the list of all your communities:

1. Click on the Stack Exchange menu on the top bar.
2. Click the **"YOUR COMMUNITIES"** link.

Here's a screenshot with a [mandatory freehand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/348196):

[image: Stack Exchange menu with the "YOUR COMMUNITIES" link outlined]

Comment: 2x click is 2x clicks – and thanks, had forgotten about that one. Imo it should till be visible on profile page. I.e. why not.

Comment: @user3342816 If you hide all of them, they will all be visible on your profile page (don't try to understand it)